# How to add space between columns with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add space between this columns, how can I do it with bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="my_h">title</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>Widget 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>Widget 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>Widget 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `col-md-offset-*`:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="my_h">title</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div>Widget 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>Widget 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>Widget 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about this [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap always uses 15px padding on columns to separate the content of the columns.

So there is a standard 30px space between column content

Answer (score 1):

Try this with css and offset

```
 .widget-box {
      padding: 20px 5px;
    }

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="my_h">title</h1>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="widget-box">Widget 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="widget-box">Widget 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="widget-box">Widget 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR

**Set offset**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="my_h">title</h1>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="widget-box">Widget 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="widget-box">Widget 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="widget-box">Widget 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggested solution for a long-term, personalised fix**

If you are looking to maintain the 12-column grid system, and not use empty columns to create the spacing you're looking for, the best solution for you would be to customize your own settings for Bootstrap.

Most specifically, this link: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

**Quick and dirty fix**

If, on the other hand, you want to use empty columns, the `offset` classes are here for you. Bear in mind you will probably struggle to align 3 columns correctly:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="my_h">title</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div>Widget 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div>Widget 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div>Widget 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```